# UIBarButtomItem tintColor not working if i change the appearance of UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I have a instance of UIBarButtonItem.
I want to change the tintColor of the UIBarButtonItem to orangeColor.
And I also change the appearance of UITextField to orangeColor in the Appdelegate.

```
// some view controller
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

[barButtonItem setTintColor:[KLStyle colorTitleOrangle]];


// Appdelegate.h
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
}
```

There is a problem if i don't comment `[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];` , the tintColor of UIBarButtonItem will be wrong. It's still default tintColor blue.

If i comment it, the tintColor of UIBarButtonItem will be correct.

Is there someone known why this will be happen?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Strangely enough, I've got the same problem. I believe this to be a bug and will file a report at Apple, I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Man... just had this problem. Banging my damn head against the wall! I didn't see this answer till I had already figured it out though... :(

Comment: Also i have the same identical problem

Comment: The tintColor of UIBarButtonItem will be wrong as well as setting the tintColor appearance of UIImage

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                              [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:75.0/255 blue:152.0/255 alpha:1],
                                                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                              [UIColor grayColor],
                                                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                              [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                                                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                              nil]
                                                                                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                              [UIColor grayColor],
                                                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                              [UIColor grayColor],
                                                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                              [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                                                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                              nil]
                                                                                       forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```